# Proving the metrics $d_1(x,y) $ and $d_2(x,y) $ are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

Prove that the metrics $$ d_1(x,y) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x_n - y_n|}{ n^{2}(1+|x_n - y_n|)} $$ and $$ d_2(x,y) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x_n - y_n|}{2^{n}(1+|x_n - y_n|)} $$ are equivalent on $ \omega = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} $, the set of all real sequences.

I think to prove it, I have to show that fixed $ x\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} $, $ \epsilon > 0 $ and $ \gamma = f(\epsilon) $

$$ d_1(x,y)\geq \epsilon \implies d_2(x,y)\geq\gamma \tag{1}$$

$$ d_2(x,y)\geq \epsilon \implies d_1(x,y)\geq\gamma \tag{2}$$

But I do not know how should I choose $\gamma$ as a form of $\epsilon$ so I can prove this.

Comment: You need to show that $c_1d_1(x,y)\le d_2(x,y)\le c_2d_1(x,y)$.

Comment: @xpaul is it okay also show $c_1d_2(x,y)\le d_1(x,y)\le c_2d_2(x,y)$

Comment: @Pumpkin yes it is as the latter implies the first one, indeed $c_1d_2\leq d_1 \leq c_2d_2$  implies $\frac{1}{c_2}d_1\leq d_2 \leq \frac{1}{c_1}d_1$

Comment: @xpaul   . It's not true.  The metrics $d_1,d_2$ are $not$ uniformly equivalent.  But two metrics can be equivalent without being uniformly equivalent.... Let $x(j)=(x_{j,n})_n$ where $x_{j,j}=1$  and $x_{j,n}=0$ if $n\ne j.$ Let $y=(y_n)_n$ where $y_n=0$ for all $n.$ Then $\sup_j \frac {d_1(x(j),y)}{d_2(x(j),y)} =$ $\sup_j 2^j/j^2=$ $\infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $d_2(x,y)\leq 2d_1(x,y)$ because $2^{-n}<2n^{-2}$ for all $n\in \Bbb N.$ So the topology $T_2$ generated by $d_2$ is a subset of the topology $T_1$ generated by $d_1.$

To show that $T_1\subset T_2$ it suffices to show that for $x\in \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ and for $\delta >0$ there exists $\delta'\in (0,\delta]$ and $\delta^*>0$  such that  $B_{d_2}(x,\delta^*)\subset B_{d_1}(x,\delta').$

We will repeatedly use the fact that $f(t)=t/(1+t)$ is an increasing function for $t\geq 0.$

Let $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-2}.$

Let $\delta'=\min (\delta, 1, 2S).$  (Ignoring the fact that $2S>1.$ We will need $\delta' /2S\leq 1.$)

Take $n_1\in \Bbb N$ large enough that $\sum_{n=1+n_1}^{\infty}n^{-2}< \delta' /2.$

Let $\delta^*=(1/4S) \cdot \delta' \cdot  2^{-n_1}.$

If $y\in B_{d_2}(x,\delta^*)$ and $j\leq n_1$ then $|x_j-y_j|<\delta' /2S.$ Because if not , then $$d_2(x,y)\geq 2^{-j}\frac {|x_j-y_j|}{1+|x_j-y_j|}\geq$$     $$\geq 2^{-j}\frac {\delta' /2S}{1+\delta' /2S}\geq 2^{-j}\frac {\delta' /2S}{2}\geq 2^{-n_1}\frac {\delta' /2S} {2}\geq \delta^*.$$

So for $y\in B_{d_2}(x,\delta^*)$ we have   $$d_1(x,y)< \sum_{n=1}^{n_1} n^{-2}\frac {\delta' /2S }{1+\delta' /2S}+\sum_{n=1+n_1}^{\infty}n^{-2}<$$ $$<(\delta' /2 S)  S+\sum_{n=1+n_1}^{\infty}n^{-2}<\delta' /2+\delta' /2=\delta'.$$

Comment: The idea is to take a sufficiently long initial (finite) segment $(1/1^2,...,1/(n_1)^2)$ of the sequence $(1/n^2)_{n\in \Bbb N}$  and then take $\delta^* $ small enough that if  $d_2(x,y)<\delta^*$  then $ |x_j-y_j|$ is  "miniscule" for each $j\leq n_1. $  And the "tail" of the summation for $d_1(x,y)$ (the terms with $n>n_1$) will also be "small enough" if $n_1$ is large enough